# SQL Group by main category in self-referenced table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get a list of total sales grouped by the main category and `Seller`. Note that there can be sales on the main category (this is the best example I can think of at the moment).

**Source table**

```
+--------------------------------------+
|ID   |Name        |Seller|Qty|ParentID|
+--------------------------------------+
|10   |Egg         |John  |5  |NULL    |
|10   |Egg         |Anna  |2  |NULL    |
|10-01|Egg - Small |John  |3  |10      |
|10-01|Egg - Small |Anna  |4  |10      |
|10-02|Egg - Medium|John  |2  |10      |
|10-02|Egg - Medium|Bob   |11 |10      |
|10-03|Egg - Large |Anna  |7  |10      |
+--------------------------------------+
```

**Desired output**

```
+------------------+
|ID|Name|Seller|Qty|
+------------------+
|10|Egg |John  |10 | <- SUM of all sales John has made for any type of egg
|10|Egg |Anna  |13 |
|10|Egg |Bob   |11 |
+------------------+
```

I'm getting close with this query, but if someone has not made a sale on the main category, they will get the wrong `Name` when I use `MIN(Name)`.

**Current query**

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(t1.ID, 1, 2) AS 'ID',
    MIN(t1.Name) AS 'Name', 
    t1.Seller, 
    SUM(t1.Qty) AS 'Qty'
FROM EggTest t1
GROUP BY 
    SUBSTRING(t1.ID, 1, 2),
    t1.Seller
```

**Current output**

```
+--------------------------+
|ID|Name        |Seller|Qty|
+--------------------------+
|10|Egg         |Anna  |13 |
|10|Egg - Medium|Bob   |11 | <- Bob has not made sales on the main category
|10|Egg         |John  |10 |
+--------------------------+
```

**EDIT:** Seeing that multiple answers have already suggested `SUBSTRING(Name, 1, 3)` it will not work for me. `Name` does not always start with "Egg".

**Update:**

Now trying this query:

```
WITH report AS(
  SELECT 
    ID = CASE WHEN s.ParentID IS NOT NULL THEN s.ParentID ELSE s.ID END,
    Name = CASE WHEN s.ParentID IS NOT NULL THEN p.Name ELSE s.Name END,
    s.Seller,
    s.Qty
  FROM EggTest s
  LEFT JOIN EggTest p ON p.ID = s.ParentID
)

SELECT ID, Name, Seller, SUM(Qty) AS 'Total'
FROM report
GROUP BY ID, Name, Seller;
```

But I am getting this strange result:

```
+--------------------+
|ID|Name|Seller|Total|
+--------------------+
|10|Egg |Anna  |24   | <- Wrong (Should be 13)
|10|Egg |Bob   |22   | <- Wrong (Should be 11)
|10|Egg |John  |15   | <- Correct(!!)
+--------------------+
```

In the `report`-table I'm getting some duplicates:

```
+------------------+
|ID|Name|Seller|Qty|
+------------------+
|10|Egg |John  |5  |
|10|Egg |Anna  |2  |
|10|Egg |John  |3  |
|10|Egg |John  |3  |
|10|Egg |Anna  |4  |
|10|Egg |Anna  |4  |
|10|Egg |John  |2  |
|10|Egg |John  |2  |
|10|Egg |Anna  |7  |
|10|Egg |Anna  |7  |
|10|Egg |Bob   |11 |
|10|Egg |Bob   |11 |
+------------------+
```

Comment: you can get what you want in two steps using cte, first convert all categories to their main category and then apply the group by ( this will show you Bob has 11 and the name of category Egg and not Egg - Medium

Comment: You can make distinct, it will work and if you add include the seller in the left join you will get Name = null for Bob, so the best way to make `distinct`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will consider the source table name as [**Sales**]

You can use the following

```
with report as(
   select ID = case when s.ParentID is not null then s.ParentID else s.ID end,
          Name= case when s.ParentID is not null then p.Name else s.Name end,
          s.Seller,
          s.Qty
   from Sales s
   left join Sales p on p.ID = s.ParentID and p.Seller = s.Seller
)
select ID,Name,Seller,sum(Qty) as Qty
from report
group by ID,Name,Seller
```

Here a [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/98949/8) using `Distinct`

Here a [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/98949/9) by including the `Seller in the left join` , which will give you Name of the item for Seller Bob as `NULL`, the left join should work if you have correct data integrity which means separate table for the Items and Categories

replying on your last comment, here a [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/98949/20) how to make your data clear

Hope this will help you

Comment: This is very good, totally makes sense and the `report`-table looks correct. But I am getting wrong `Qty` for both Anna and Bob. I've edited my original post with the results I now get.

Comment: Yes this is very clear because you have no unique ID, the best way in order to get unique Join is to include also the Seller, i  will update my solution, so the left join will be `LEFT JOIN EggTest p ON p.ID = s.ParentID and p.Seller = s.Seller`

Comment: That works for the most part. The problem now is that not everyone has sales within the main category. Bob's sales now has the name `NULL`, because he can't be found in `p.Seller`. You mention a unique ID - could adding an ID for each row help me here? EDIT: Guess you beat me to it. ´DISTINCT` seems to fix it all.

Comment: for a better solution you need to correct the names of the items then you find the sum, I prepared another demo to show you how, so the cte `initial` is to link the Name to its correct name and then you update the data you have by using the desired `ID` and `Name` in `report` cte, and finally you apply the grouping

Answer (score 0):

Try this query. If you need explanation, ask :) But it's rather simple query :)

```
SELECT MAX(SUBSTRING(ID, 1, 2)) AS ID, 
       SUBSTRING(Name, 1, 3) AS Name,
       Seller, 
       SUM(Qty) AS Qty 
FROM TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY Seller, SUBSTRING(Name, 1, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if `ID` is always in the format `nn[-nn]` and if `Name` can  handle other stuffs than eggs...

This shoud works in any case:

```
;with
m as (
    select *, nullif(charindex('-', ID), 0) div_id, nullif(charindex(' - ', name), 0) div_cat
    from EggTest 
),
c as (
    select *, 
        SUBSTRING(ID, 1, isnull(div_id-1, 1000)) main_ID, 
        SUBSTRING(name, 1, isnull(div_cat-1, 1000)) main_cat, 
        nullif(SUBSTRING(name, isnull(div_cat, 1000)+2, 1000), '') sub_cat
    from m
)
select main_ID ID, main_cat [Name], Seller, sum(qty) Qty
from c
group by main_ID, main_cat, seller
```

Outputs:

```
ID  Name    Seller  Qty
10  Egg     Anna    13
10  Egg     Bob     11
10  Egg     John    10
```